# Magento 2.3.5 - Remove product groups in the cart programmatically

Tags: magento2, product, php, cart, quoteitem

I'm trying to remove simple and virtual products in groups through a custom form I created.

The code is this and it seems to work but in reality when you reload the page the minicart does not update and in the shopping cart there always seems to be something left because the summary of the cart is always visible with sub total at 0.00.
Why?

ShoppingCart.php

```
namespace Catalog\Product\Block;

use Magento\Checkout\Model\Cart as CustomerCart;

class ShoppingCart extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template
{
    protected $cart;
    
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context $context,
        \Magento\Checkout\Model\Session $checkoutSession,
        CustomerCart $cart,
        array $data = []
    ) {
        $this->_checkoutSession = $checkoutSession;
        $this->cart = $cart;
        parent::__construct($context, $data);
    }
    
    public function getCart(){
        return $this->cart;
    }

    /**
     * Get quote object associated with cart. By default it is current customer session quote
     *
     * @return \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote
     */
    public function getQuoteData()
    {
        $this->_checkoutSession->getQuote();
        if (!$this->hasData('quote')) {
            $this->setData('quote', $this->_checkoutSession->getQuote());
        }
        return $this->_getData('quote');
    }
}
```

My action form file: RemoveItemCart.phtml

```
$blockCMS = $block->getLayout()->createBlock('\CMSpage\CMS\Block\BaseUrl');
$baseUrl = $blockCMS->getBaseUrl();
$currentUrl = $this->getUrl('*/*/*', ['_current' => true, '_use_rewrite' => true]);

$blockCart = $block->getLayout()->createBlock('\Catalog\Product\Block\ShoppingCart');
$blockGetCart = $blockCart->getCart();
$blockCartItems = $blockCart->getQuoteData()->getAllVisibleItems();

    foreach($blockCartItems as $item){
        $text = $_POST['valDelPosPrin'];
        $mystring = $item->getPosprintprod();
        if(strpos($mystring, $text)  !== false){
            $blockGetCart->removeItem($item->getItemId())->save();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

check the below code.it's working for login and guest customer cart item removes code.

```
<?php

    protected $quoteFactory;
    protected $quoteItem;
    protected $quoteMaskFactory;
    protected $quoteRepository;
....
    public function __construct(
        ......
        Magento\Quote\Model\QuoteFactory $quoteFactory,
        Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Item $quoteItem,
        Magento\Quote\Model\QuoteIdMaskFactory $quoteMaskFactory,
        Magento\Quote\Api\CartRepositoryInterface $quoteRepository
    ) {
        $this->quoteFactory = $quoteFactory;
        $this->quoteItem = $quoteItem;
        $this->quoteMaskFactory = $quoteMaskFactory;
        $this->quoteRepository = $quoteRepository;
    }
    .........

    public function deleteCartItems($customerId, $quoteId)
    {
        try {
            $quote = $this->quoteFactory->create()->load($quoteId);
            foreach ($quote->getAllItems() as $item) {
                $this->quoteItem->load($item->getItemId())->delete();
            }
            return true;
        } catch (\Exception $exc) {
            return false;
        }
    }

   
    public function deleteGuestCartItems($maskId)
    {
        try {
            $quoteId = $this->quoteMaskFactory->create()->load($maskId, 'masked_id')->getQuoteId();
            if (empty($quoteId)) {
                return false;
            }

            $quote = $this->quoteFactory->create()->load($quoteId);
            foreach ($quote->getAllItems() as $item) {
                $this->quoteItem->load($item->getItemId())->delete();
            }
            return true;
        } catch (\Exception $exc) {
            return false;
        }
    }

    public function deleteCartItemsByIds($customerId, $cartId)
    {
        $requestParams = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"), true);
        try {
            $quote = $this->quoteRepository->getActive($cartId);
            foreach ($quote->getAllVisibleItems() as $item)
            {
                if(in_array($item->getSku(),$requestParams['items'])){
                   $quote->deleteItem($item)->save();
                }
            }
            $this->quoteRepository->save($quote);
            return true;
        } catch (\Exception $exc) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for reply. I will try your code very soon!